# Wordpress - Show Post Preview when not logged in

Tags: wordpress, post

I want to set up a wordpress site that will show the title and the first X number of characters/words to users who are not logged in (similar to the read more option). When they click read more they will be sent to a page that says something like "Thank you for your interest... If you would like to read more login or register for free! [registration form/login].

I understand that I can just hide infromation by uses this code in page.php or in the post list template:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() )
{ ?>
  .....Content here......
<?php
{  ?>
```

And then add code to take them to the registration page with the message. This would work if I just wanted to hide the content and show the title but how can I use this while showing a specific amount of characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use  `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>`  as preview. It will print the trimmed version of content and for logged in user `<?php the_content(); ?>`